# ssh agent forwarding not working after ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, 20.04, git

SSH agent forwarding was perfectly working when I was using xubuntu 19.10, after I upgrade my system to xubuntu 20.04, its not working anymore. I never change /etc/ssh/config or /home/.ssh/config . Here is my current ~/.ssh/config looks like :

```
Host my_remote_server_ip
  ForwardAgent yes
```

After system upgrade when I try to run git pull in remote server I got this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that the ssh agent is not starting automatically. I add the following to my `.bashrc` (see [here](https://gist.github.com/bsara/5c4d90db3016814a3d2fe38d314f9c23)):

`vi ~/.bashrc`

```
# Start SSH Agent
#----------------------------

SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function run_ssh_env {
  . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
}

function start_ssh_agent {
  echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
  ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
  echo "succeeded"
  chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"

  run_ssh_env;

  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
  run_ssh_env;
  ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
    start_ssh_agent;
  }
else
  start_ssh_agent;
fi
```

After a logout and login with user it is working like it was in ubuntu before.